# How does the unit circle relate to triangles with a hypotenuse larger than 1?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is a unit circle representative of all triangles, even triangles larger than the circle itself? I understand that $\sin\theta= Y$ and $\cos\theta = X$, but that is only because the hypotenuse is $1$. What if the hypotenuse is $2$ for example? How is $\sin\theta = Y$ still? How does the unit circle form a basis for all angles?

Comment: You can always just normalize the hypotenuse for any right triangle.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Ratios of corresponding sides of similar triangles are the same

Comment: If the hypothenus is 2 then $sin(\theta) = \frac{Y}{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I think a question like this has been asked and answered at least once before.

Comment: Here are a couple of related (though subtly different) questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939494/why-is-the-unit-circle-the-preferred-circle-to-derive-values-of-trig-functions and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307614/what-is-the-unit-circle-in-relation-to-a-arbitrary-right-triangle

Answer (score 1):

[image: trigonometry_diagram]

For a directed angle $\theta$ with vertex at the origin and initial side on the positive $x$-axis, the point at which the terminal side of the angle $\theta$ intersects the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is defined to be $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$.

If the terminal side of angle $\theta$ intersects the circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ at the point $(x, y)$, then by similar triangles,
\begin{align*}
\frac{|x|}{r} & = \frac{|\cos\theta|}{1} = |\cos\theta|\\
\frac{|y|}{r} & = \frac{|\sin\theta|}{1} = |\sin\theta|
\end{align*}
Moreover, since $r > 0$, the sign of $x$ agrees with the sign of $\cos\theta$ and the sign of $y$ agrees with $\sin\theta$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta & = \frac{x}{r}\\
\sin\theta & = \frac{y}{r}
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\tan\theta & = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{y}{x}\\
\csc\theta & = \frac{1}{\sin\theta} = \frac{r}{y}\\
\sec\theta & = \frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \frac{r}{x}\\
\cot\theta & = \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If a triangle has the same proportions as one that fits a unit circle, it is called similar. Under these conditions, if you take the ratios of any $2$ sides, you will come up with the same $number(s)$ which mean the same angle(s) as though it fit the unit circle.